# How to traverse to next page with scrapy?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Hello Thank you for taking the time to help much appreciated.

Issue: I have tried to link up the spider to keep traversing to next page
but it does not work so i was hoping to get some pointers on what i'm doing wrong.

```
class infoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'info_spider'
start_urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cars']

def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = '.yt-lockup'
    for content in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

        NAME_SELECTOR = '.yt-lockup-byline a ::text'
        IMAGE_SELECTOR = 'img ::attr(src)'
        yield {
            'name': content.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'image': content.css(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        }

    NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.yt-uix-button-content a ::attr(href)'
    next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

Update: It returns a few results but does not continue to traverse to the next page. I have Located that it gives a random key to each next buttons
would need to find a way around that.

Please let me know if you need more information (do not downvote please!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to use a Link Extractor. you can use the set of rules to specify the next page link. Here is the official documentation
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

```
class infoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'info_spider'
start_urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=cars']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('.yt-uix-button-content a ::attr(href)')), callback="parse_page", follow=True),
)

def parse_page(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = '.yt-lockup'
    for content in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

        NAME_SELECTOR = '.yt-lockup-byline a ::text'
        IMAGE_SELECTOR = 'img ::attr(src)'
        yield {
            'name': content.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            'image': content.css(IMAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        }
```

Comment: Can the rule only get class or can it also grab info from say other html types other then class? like a data-type etc..

Comment: My understanding is that the LinkExtractor is creating a list of links to follow and your parse_page function will run for each link it puts in the list. If you are having issues with what is being returned/collecting data-types maybe it's a separate issue. Can you post what your items.py file looks like?
If the problem is that the next page link can't be identified using `.yt-uix-button-content a ::attr(href)` try using a differen't way to restrict the path like restrict-xpath() instead of restrict-css(). https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp this is a great link for learning xpath

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.yt-uix-button-content a ::attr(href)'
```

to

```
NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.yt-uix-button-content a::attr(href)'
```

OR change your last lines of code to

```
try:
    next_page = response.css('.yt-uix-button-content a::attr(href)').extract()[0]

    yield scrapy.Request(
        response.urljoin(next_page),
        callback=self.parse
    )
except IndexError:
     pass
```

Comment: you can use `.extract_first()` to avoid errors. If you use `.extract_first('')` then you'll get plain domain url (i.e. http://example.com) which most likely be filtered by scrapy dupe filter so you don't even need to do checks if you are going for full lazy approach :)

Comment: @Granitosaurus i'am using .extract_first() don't quite understand?

Comment: @Umair yes same result tried them both, they return few fields of data and then finnish.

Comment: @Umair i have updated with more notes please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @EVX are you scraping Youtube? Use this css selector `#content > div > div > div > div.branded-page-v2-primary-col > div > div.branded-page-v2-body.branded-page-v2-primary-column-content > div.branded-page-box.search-pager.spf-link > a:nth-child(8)`

Comment: @Umair Thanks question would i need to use xpath to have that as my selector not sure how to implement sorry still trying to figure out the selectors in scrapy :)

Comment: In inspect-element view, you can right-click and click on `Copy CSS Selector` or `Copy xPath` in Google Chrome ... and use that selector. To use Css Selector, use `response.css()` method and to use xpath, use `response.xpath()`

Comment: @Umair both xpath and css does not work i does not go to the next page so strange..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **RULES**

```
rules = (
         Rule(
              LinkExtractor(
                            restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(@class, "yt-uix-button-content")]/a'),
              callback='self.parse'),

         )
```

another suggeston, do not overwrite **parse** function.

Comment: as my update mentioned there seems to be a issue with the class returning what is needed.